# Conditional featured image with youtube thumbnail in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

Basically what I am trying to do here is: Display the youtube thumbnail. If no youtube thumbnail -> Display the Featured image for the post. If no featured image -> Display the fallback image.

However it seems I am doing something wrong because the webpage displays blank.

```
<?php
            // Check if the post has a Youtube thumbnail (using custom field video_url)
    if get_post_meta($post->ID,'video_url',true)
        echo '<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/' . get_post_meta($post->ID,'video_url',true) . '/0.jpg"/>';
            // Check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it
    else ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '" >';
        the_post_thumbnail('frontpage-thumb');
        echo '</a>';
            // If the post does not have a featured image then display the fallback image
    } else {
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '" ><img src="'. get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/fallback-featured-image-index.jpg" /></a>';}
    ?>
```

The general code for displaying the youtube thumbnail with custom fields is `<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'video_url',true);?>/0.jpg"/>` I just can't get it to work with the conditional statements...

Answer (score 1):

In your first `if` condition, you have wrong syntax and the PHP must be closed

```
if (get_post_meta($post->ID,'video_url',true)) //
```

Correct code

```
<?php

    if (get_post_meta($post->ID,'video_url',true)) ?>
        echo '<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'video_url',true);?>/0.jpg"/>';

    // Check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it
    else ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '" >';
        the_post_thumbnail('frontpage-thumb');
        echo '</a>';

    // If the post does not have a featured image then display the fallback image
    } else {
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '" ><img src="'. get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/fallback-featured-image-index.jpg" /></a>';}
?>
```

Comment: Please now check it  I did edit my answer. if any problem then tell me

Comment: You have invalid code. Please remove `?>` from `true)) ?>` Also, this did not work. Nothing is being displayed.